# How to access the id of a TextBox in the repeater code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater below;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptRE" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="headingCollapse2" runat="server">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#link<%#Eval("IDmessage")%>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="link<%#Eval("IDmessage")%>">
                <asp:TextBox ID="getid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="media">
                    <span class="avata">
                        <img class="media" src="../pics/<%#Eval("Picsender")%>"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <h6 class="list"><%#Eval("SubjectMessage")%></h6>
                    <p class="ltext">
                        <span><%#Eval("DateSendMessage")%></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="link<%#Eval("IDmessage")%>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingCollapse2" class="card-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
            <p><%#Eval("ContentMessage")%></p>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In line 5 I have a textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="getid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I can't get the ID of the TextBox code-behind. Is there any specific reason? Does anybody know how to get it?

Thanks

Comment: It's index based: `var textbox = (TextBox)RptRE.Items[index].FindControl("getid");`

Comment: What is the index?

Comment: You bind multiple items to a Repeater, so you need to know in which item you want to find the TextBox. It's an integer. So if you want the fifth item you use `Items[4].FindControl`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. I want to get the ID text. How will i do it ??  **<asp:TextBox ID="getid" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="<%#Eval("IDmessage")%>"></asp:TextBox>**

Comment: See my demo....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a simple demo with 2 examples of how to get the data out of the Repeater. One example is per row and the other all rows at once. Just make sure you bind data in an `IsPostBack` check.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptRE" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptRE_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="getid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="This Item" CommandName="Show" />
        <hr />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="All Items" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Code behind

```
protected void RptRE_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get the correct textbox from the ItemIndex
    var textbox = (TextBox)RptRE.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("getid");

    //show result
    Label1.Text = textbox.Text;
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptRE.Items)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("getid");
        Label1.Text += textbox.Text + "<br>";
    }
}
```